# How can I use a single partial to render each object in a collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, collections

I have a working partial for an instance of my Quote class, `_quote.html.erb`, I would like to use this same partial to render each object within the collection provided by the index action. However, I am getting stuck and can no longer see where I am going wrong. An instance variable naming issue, a controller crud action format issue? Code below:

**quotes_controller.rb**

```
class QuotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [ :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy ]
  # before_action :owners_only, only: [ :show, :edit, :index, :update, :destroy ]

  def new
    @quote = Quote.new
  end

  def create
    # @quote = Quote.new(quote_params)
    @quote = current_user.quotes.new(quote_params)
    if @quote.save
        redirect_to quote_url(@quote), notice: 'Quote request created'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    # @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])
    @quote = current_user.quotes.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @quotes = current_user.quotes.all
  end

  def edit
    @quote = current_user.quotes.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @quote = current_user.quotes.find(params[:id])
    if @quote.update_attributes(quote_params)
      redirect_to quote_path(@quote)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @quote = current_user.quotes.find(params[:id])
    @quote.destroy
    redirect_to quotes_path
  end

private

  def quote_params
    params.require(:quote).permit(:gla, :prev_cover, :co_name, :co_number, :postcode, :industry, :lives_overseas, 
                                  :scheme_start_date, :payment_frequency, :commission_level)
  end
end
```

**_quote.html.erb**

```
<section id="quote">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <div class="panel panel-success panel-quote">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <strong>GLA</strong>
        </div>
      <div class="panel-body text-center">
         <p><strong>Quote ID; <%= @quote.id %></strong></p>
      </div>

      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
          <td>Company name</td>
          <td><%= @quote.co_name %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Company number</td>
          <td><%= @quote.co_number %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Office postcode</td>
          <td><%= @quote.postcode %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Industry</td>
          <td><%= @quote.industry %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Previous cover</td>
          <td><%= @quote.prev_cover %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lives overseas</td>
          <td><%= @quote.lives_overseas %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Scheme start date</td>
          <td><%= @quote.scheme_start_date %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Payment frequency</td>
          <td><%= @quote.payment_frequency %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Commission level</td>
          <td><%= @quote.commission_level %></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @quotes.each do |q| %>
  <%= render :partial => "quote", :collection => q %>
<% end %>
```

Am i doing something blindingly obvious here that someone can point out for me, been staring so long I can't see it any more!

If I run:

```
<% @quotes.each do |q| %>
  <%= q.co_name %>
<% end %>
```

The index page renders the `co_name` values just fine, showing that the collection does get through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this:

```
<% @quotes.each do |q| %>
  <%= render :partial => "quote", :collection => q %>
<% end %>
```

Might be something more like this:

```
<% @quotes.each do |quote| %>
  <%= render :partial => "quote", locals: {quote: quote} %>
<% end %>
```

And then in your partial, at the top, do something like:

```
<% @quote = local_assigns[:quote] %>
<section id="quote">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <div class="panel panel-success panel-quote">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <strong>GLA</strong>
        </div>
      <div class="panel-body text-center">
         <p><strong>Quote ID; <%= @quote.id %></strong></p>
      </div>

      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
          <td>Company name</td>
          <td><%= @quote.co_name %></td>
        </tr>
        ...
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then I think you'll be on your way.

Comment: Thanks #jvillian, that worked perfectly, helped me out of a being lost and helped me see what I need understand better, ie partials, passing them arguments and viariables .